# Square Root Regularization and High Loss

Tags: neural-network, loss-function, pytorch, regularization

I am testing out square root regularization (explained ahead) in a pytorch implementation of a neural network. Square root regularization, henceforth ***l1/2***, is just like *l2* regularization, but instead of squaring the weights, I take the square root of their absolute value. To implement it I penalize the loss as such in pytorch:

```
for p in model.parameters():
  loss += lambda * torch.sqrt(p.abs()).sum()
```

`p.abs()` is the absolute value of `p`, i.e the weights, `torch.sqrt()` is the square root and `.sum()` is the sum of the result for the individual weights. `lambda` is the penalization factor.
With no regularization, the loss settles around `0.4`. With `lambda=100`, the loss settles somewhere around `0.45`, **if I use l2 or l1 regularization**. Interestingly enough with `lambda=0.001`, the final value for the loss is around `0.44`. Now if I use ***l1/2*** with the same lambda it settles around `5000`! This just does not make sense to me. If the regularization is such an overwhelming factor in the loss, then SGD has got to bring the (absolute value) of the weights down until, the penalty from the regularization is balanced with the actual classification from the *Cross Entropy Loss* I'm using - **I know this is not the case**, because the train and validation accuracies, are around the same of the original network (without regularization) at the end of training. I also know that the regularization is indeed happening in all three cases, as the loss in the early epochs differ significantly).
Is this to be expected or is this some error in my code or pytorch's SGD?

*One more note* If use *l1/2* with a small `lambda` like `0.001`, the loss comes down to around `0.5` and **then becomes `nan` around epoch 70**. For `lambda=0.01`, it becomes ~`1.0` and then **`nan` around the same epoch**. For `lambda=0.1`, loss becomes `5` **but no `nan` anymore for this `lambda` or any value higher (in 120 epochs total)**. For `lambda=1.0`, loss settles at ~`50`- as expected: apparently the weights settle down at a point where the sum of their square roots equals ~ `50`, regardless of `lambda`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using $L_p$ norm with $p < 1$ for regularization is **the gradient**.

Regularization term is used to force the parameters to be closer to zero. For this to work, when a parameter goes closer to zero, the gradient of regularization term, i.e. its contribution in updating the parameter, should decrease as well or at least remain constant.

However, by going closer to zero, the gradient increases unboundedly for $p < 1$, which causes radical changes in parameters, leading to your observations. Here is a visual plot for root $r$, absolute $a$, and squared $s$ regularization terms in one dimension ([drawn here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)):

[image]

As you can see, for root regularization, the gradient explodes to infinity as we get closer to zero which is **in conflict** with our intention to bring the parameters close to zero.

For the sake of completeness, here is what a 1D parameter update with root regularization looks like:
$$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n + \alpha \frac{d L(\theta)}{d \theta}\Bigr|_{\theta=\theta_n} = \theta_n + \alpha \left(\frac{d l(\theta)}{d \theta}\Bigr|_{\theta=\theta_n} \pm \lambda \frac{1}{\color{red}{\sqrt{|\theta_n|}}}\right)$$
where $L(\theta) = l(\theta) + \lambda \sqrt{|\theta|}$.

You can spot the trouble! The more we get close to zero, the less we get close to zero!

Comment: Beautifully explained. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of square root, `ln(1+abs(p))` has a similar curve but avoids the gradient issue near 0.

[image]

I am considering using this loss function in a regression problem were AI has trouble distinguishing between two valid values and ends up guessing in the middle (if squaring the error) or anywhere in-between (if using mean absolute error), which in our case is pretty bad.